# hspace not working in tabular environment

Tags: tables, indentation

I have the following code in LaTeX.

```
\begin{tabular}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash} m{2cm} | >{\arraybackslash}  m{10cm} }
some text & text1 \newline
            text2 \newline
            text3 \\ 
\end{tabular}
```

I would like to indent text3 in the same cell as text1 and text2. I have tried adding a `\hspace{2mm}` in front of *text3* but it does not work. Any idea on how to solve this?

**EDIT**

I have tried David Carlisle's suggestion of using `\hspace*`. This works fine if *text3* does not fill more than one line. If it does, then the next line is not indented. How can I fix this?

Here is the output using `\hspace*`:
[image: Output using \hspace*]

And the corresponding code:

```
\begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash} m{2cm}|m{11cm}}
    text & text1 \newline
           text2 \newline
    \hspace*{1pt} text3
    \\ 
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Are you looking to apply this type of hanging indentation to all cells, or just this one particular cell?

Comment: unrelated to tables use `\hspace*`

Comment: Just this one particular cell.

Comment: `\parindent 2mm \hangindent 2mm text3 \lipsum[1][1-2]`

Comment: the next line is indented by 1pt, but you have `\hspace*{1pt} text3` so allowing a line break at the space between `\hspace*{1pt}` and `text3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash} m{2cm} | m{10cm} }
some text &
  \lipsum[1][1-2]

  \lipsum[1][3-4]

  \hangindent=1em \hangafter=0
  \lipsum[1][5-8]
\\ 
\end{tabular} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! That is exactly what I wanted.